# Are assertions removed in release build?

Tags: contract-debugging, optimization, assert

Are `assert()` removed in release build?

Please show an authoritative document documenting that they are removed or no removed.

Comment: Please explain what 'release build' means (including technical details).

Comment: @goodvibration `solc` with optimizer enabled.

Comment: Solc's optimizer does not remove `assert` statements AFAIK. It is true that every `assert` that you put in your code, you should theoretically remove once you are 100% sure that it is safe to do so. In other words, `assert` is designated for bugs in your code (in contrast with `require`, which is designated for invalid user input). So technically speaking, right before releasing your code, you should be in a state where you feel safe to remove all of your `assert` statements. That said, the optimizer is not designated to do this for you, i.e., it is under your own responsibility.

Comment: `Please show an authoritative document documenting that they are removed or no removed` - there is obviously no such document. Do you seriously expect an official document about solc (or any other product for that matter) to state everything that it **doesn't do**???